# Get the Text from the next_sibling - BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape Restaurants from [this URL](http://www.accorhotels.com/gb/hotel-5548-mercure-niederbronn-hotel/restaurant.shtml)

```
for rests in dining_soup.select("div.infos-restos"):
    
    for rest in rests.select("h3"):
        safe_print("            Rest Nsme: "+rest.text)
        print(rest.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.contents)
```

outputs

```
<div class="descriptif-resto">
<p>
<strong>Type of cuisine</strong>:International</p>
<p>
<strong>Opening hours</strong>:06:00-23:30</p>
<p>The Food Square bar and restaurant offers a varied menu in an elegant and welcoming setting. In fine weather you can also enjoy your meal next to the pool or relax on the garden terrace.</p>
</div>
```

and

`print(rest.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)`

outputs always empty

So my question is how do I scrape `Type of cuisine` and `opening hours` from that Div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening hours and cuisine are in `"descriptif-resto"` text:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://www.accorhotels.com/gb/hotel-5548-mercure-niederbronn-hotel/restaurant.shtml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

print(soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"descriptif-resto"}).text)

Type of cuisine:Brasserie

Opening hours:12:00 - 14:00 / 19:00 - 22:00
```

The name is in the first h3 tag, the type and opening hours are in the two p tags:

```
name = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"infos-restos"}).h3.text
det = soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"descriptif-resto"}).p   

hours = det.find_next("p").text
tpe = det.text
print(name)
print(hours)
print(tpe)

LA STUB DU CASINO

Opening hours:12:00 - 14:00 / 19:00 - 22:00

Type of cuisine:Brasserie
```

Ok so some parts don't have both opening hours and cuisine so you will have to fine tune that but this gets all the info:

```
from itertools import chain

all_dets = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"infos-restos"})
# get all names from h3 tagsusing chain so we can zip later
names = chain.from_iterable(x.find_all("h3") for x in  all_dets) 
# get all info to extract cuisine, hours
det = chain.from_iterable(x.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"descriptif-resto"}) for x in all_dets)
# zipp appropriate details with each name
zipped  = zip(names, det)

for name, det in zipped:
    details = det.p
    name, tpe = name.text, details
    hours = details.find_next("p") if "cuisine" in det.p.text else ""
    if hours: # empty string means we have a bar
        print(name, tpe.text, hours.text)
    else:
         print(name, tpe.text)
    print("-----------------------------")

LA STUB DU CASINO 
Type of cuisine:Brasserie 
Opening hours:12:00 - 14:00 / 19:00 - 22:00
-----------------------------
RESTAURANT DU CASINO IVORY 
Type of cuisine:French 
Opening hours:19:00 - 22:00
-----------------------------
BAR DE L'HOTEL LE DOLLY 
Opening hours:10:00-01:00 
-----------------------------
BAR DES MACHINES A SOUS 
Opening hours:10:30-03:00 
-----------------------------
```

Comment: How do I get restaurant name, type of cuisine and opening hours into separate variables to later store in DB

Comment: One sec, so you just want those three?

Comment: Yes, into separate variables so I can store into DB later from my code

Comment: Thanks for the efforts ... but It restaurant `RESTAURANT DU CASINO IVORY` does not get scraped

Comment: Are you scraping multiple restaurants?

Comment: Ohh sorry ... I did not mention that in my question ... Yes I want to scrape all the Restaurants and Bars from that site

Comment: I thought you were just trying to access a particular restaurant. I will have another look but the logic will be similar

Comment: ah ok that actually makes it easier!

Comment: You can see there is  extra output for hours for the first bar because nect p goes to the next tag so you will have to use has_attr or something similar to catch that, I outlined the two issues in the output

Comment: no worries, added a fix checking cuisine is in the line is sufficient